# Display success message after form submission in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code. In this, I'm showing an alert message after sending the message through a form. I don't want to display the alert message with button. Is there any way I can show a success message without using an alert?

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit_msg'])) {
        $mbno = $_POST['mobile'];
        $campaign_text = $_POST['campaign_text'];
        $save_sms_report = $db->sms_report($mbno,$campaign_text,$date,$homepage);
        if($save_sms_report){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message sent successfully");</script>';
            echo "<script>window.top.location='campaign-manager.php?url=checked'</script>";
            //echo "<script>window.top.location='campaign-manager.php'</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("unable to send sms");</script>';
            } 
         }
```

Comment: Look this maybe, it creates flashmessage from PHP : https://mikeeverhart.net/php-flash-messages/. You can do the same in JS with toastr for example : https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr. They both display success message (or error, warning, etc.) without using alert()

Comment: You can look bootstrap alert message to, it add a block with a message according to the type you choose `alert alert-danger` is red for example, `alert alert-success` is green, etc. You can close them and add them inside your page very easily (with bootstrap). Or you can do the same front scratch with html + css, it's not that hard, add some JS to close them for example

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to amend the dialog shown by the standard alert() method as the buttons are controlled by the browser/OS.

If you need this behaviour you'll need to use a library which builds alert notifications in HTML which can be amended exactly as you require.